# CloudFlare offers DNS root CNAMEs. Any resolution gotchas to be aware of?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, a-record, cloudflare

I'm not that familiar with the inner workings of DNS, preferring to just add my CNAMEs and A records as appropriate, and leave the behind the scenes to other services. I host a few sites on Amazon S3, which clearly doesn't allow you to have an A record with a specific IP as it is a cloud service. Consequently, I have to use 301 redirects for the naked (foobar.org) domain to www.foobar.org, enforcing the use of either a third party service, or a server to do the redirects.

I noticed that Cloudflare have [started offering a service](http://blog.cloudflare.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-root-domain-cname-supp) which allows you essentially to break DNS conventions and set a CNAME for your root domain - solving the naked domain on S3 issue. However, I'm not sure what the issues are with this - is this going to cause issues for MX records, web visitors and others? What could be the unintended side effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really a `CNAME`, though, is it?  It's a configuration of where they should pull your site from when they get requests for it.

CloudFlare's service directs traffic to their own servers as a caching proxy.  Their example has a `CNAME` going to an Amazon EC2 address, but that's not the server they're going to point you to when your client queries for it; instead, they'll return the address of their own proxy host in response to your query.

If they did indeed configure a `CNAME` record on your root domain, it would indeed break your `MX` and `SOA` records - but I suspect that's not how they've implemented it.

Comment: Sounds like some privacy issues may come into play if a proxy exists.  Security issues too `How is my data secured against unauthorized access in the cache?`, also reliability issues `What is the SLA for the cached proxy`

Comment: @makerofthings7 Well, that's [the service that CloudFlare offers](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans); I'm sure their customers have asked the same questions.

Comment: "it would indeed break your MX and SOA records" The biggest issue we have seen is with MX records (generally recommend setting A records for root domain) & this is largely a DNS RFC compliance issue.

Comment: @damoncloudflare Oh, so it is a direct `CNAME` from the client's domain to... well, is it a `CNAME` to your systems, or to the client's web hosting (as in the example in the linked blog post)?

Comment: I realise this is an old answer, but I just stumbled across it. Going by https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root, it seems Cloudflare only proxies through their own servers if you turn that on. Otherwise they just look up and return the IP number of the "CNAMEd" hostname.

Answer (score 1):

Any DNS server that permits such a configuration is buggy by definition.  I wouldn't trust those DNS servers for any mission critical services.

On the other hand, this might work if Cloudflare owns all the servers for a given TLD (.biz, .com, etc) and then disallow any other record at `somehost.com` such as MX, TXT, SOA, etc.  This is unlikely, and would cause other problems down the road...